# Retrieving specific text data from all files present in a folder

Tags: automation, database, sql, document-automation

I've some SQL queries (DBT) in a folder. I've to run the dbt sql files and validate them. Before running, I've to clone the sources used in the queries. I'm going through each file and making note of every source present in it (they are very big queries) and it's taking a lot of time. It would be easier if there's an automation, such that it can retrieve the sources used in each query(file) one by one and store it in a seperate text file. The sources are mentioned like this, `FROM {{ source('schema', 'table') }}` in the query. We can use a regex to identify and find the source tables used in each query.
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.